# React on NodeJS can POST to Spring Boot REST API but can't PUT to the same API - CORS issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, cors

My React app running on Node can make GET and POST calls to my Spring Boot REST API but when it tries to call PUT the browser console shows the OPTIONS request returning 403 and the following message in the console:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/project/65: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I can make the same PUT call from Postman and that works fine.

My Spring Boot app has the following CORS configuration but this is only applies to HTML served from itself and has no impact on the React app?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:3000");
    }
}
```

A lot of Googling of enabling CORS in Node has turned up lots of stuff about Express but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: *Response to preflight request… had HTTP status code 403* — that seems to indicate the server’s forbidding OPTIONS requests for the route 'project/65'. The server instead needs to be configured to allow unauthenticated access to OPTIONS requests to that route, by responding with a 200 OK success code for those OPTIONS requests, and the appropriate response headers, including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for the response. I made sure the API is returning the correct headings but I still get the issue so I'm pretty sure it's something I need to fix in the Node server. I'm just not sure how.

Comment: We also have a similar setup of React->Node->Spring Boot. But I am able to make all the GET, POST and PUT calls without the CORS issue.
We didn't introduce changes to the Spring Boot layer because with node backend we don't encounter the cors issue. Its mainly due to the browser that blocks cross domain access for security reasons. One other thing you can try is, on the node side; var cors = require('cors');app.use(cors());

Comment: Am having the same issue.

Comment: How did you solve it @jafwatt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the browser works as enforcing cors, it is difficult to allow cors for localhost (from the browser).

Btw: that's why it works with tools (except running in a browser) , as they are no browsers, no enforcing happens.

The easiest way would be to run a Middleware node express server.

As a http server does not fill the request with cors, there should be no cors problem anymore.

So the process would be the following:

**Frontend** call request to 
**Local http Server**, **Local http Server** in turn makes a request to the **PayPal server**
So:

Frontend->localhttp - >PayPal server->localhttp->frontend

Frontend and http are not same origin, so Frontend request to local http does not care about cors